# jquery ajax long variable list error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery to pass a set of id's to a php script which does a database insert.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
$.ajax({
url: \"update.php\",
type: \"POST\",
data: { 'tmp_do_ajax': 'add-new', 'tmp_temptable': 'temptable', 'tmp_class_id': classid,  'tmp_type_id': typeId, 'tmp_time_id': timeId, 'tmp_day': day, 'tmp_month': month, 'tmp_year': year }, 
success: function(thereturn) {... etc
```

I am using the same ajax call 4 other times (in this script) with no problems. But in this particular call, I get the error (via firebug)

> ReferenceError: typeId is not defined

If I remove the typeid, then I get the same error on the next variable (timeId)

I have an alert just prior to the ajax call showing that the typeid (and all the other vars) are properly set...

I tried to wrap all the id's in single quotes and the **ajax call query worked.** However, when I grab the vars within PHP, all the vars are set to zero:

```
//get vars from POST
$tmp_type_id = $_POST['tmp_type_id'];
```

Checking the database shows that all the ids are zero...

Kind of stuck on this one... all the other ajax calls work fine...

Is there some kind of length limitation to a jquery ajax call?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery variable doesn't have any value i supposed .Please make sure that your all the jQuery variable have data before making Ajax request.

Comment: yep, confirmed all the vars have data in an alert right before the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

When wrapped with quotes, it will become value not the variable,

```
var a = "aaa";

var a = aaa;
```

has difference, first one is assigning `aaa` as value to `a`, second one in assigning value in `aaa` to `a`

According to your error,

your variables are not defined before ajax. So try passing value to your variables to get the value in `$_POST`.

Comment: yep, clear to me now... just working too much overtime this week... Thanks!